# Why my listview always sends me back one page back when I'm clicking an item?

Tags: android, listview

I am having trouble with my listview. It always sends me back to my login page whenever I press an item on the list. It supposed to go to the details page.

```
package com.example.kun.carcarkila;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.amigold.fundapter.BindDictionary;
import com.amigold.fundapter.FunDapter;
import com.amigold.fundapter.extractors.StringExtractor;
import com.amigold.fundapter.interfaces.DynamicImageLoader;
import com.kosalgeek.android.json.JsonConverter;
import com.kosalgeek.genasync12.AsyncResponse;
import com.kosalgeek.genasync12.PostResponseAsyncTask;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AsyncResponse, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
final String LOG = "HomeActivity";

private ArrayList<Product> productList;
private ListView lvProduct;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(UILConfig.config(HomeActivity.this)); // Do it on Application start

    PostResponseAsyncTask taskRead = new PostResponseAsyncTask(HomeActivity.this, this);
    taskRead.execute("http://10.0.2.2/carkila/product.php");


}

@Override
public void processFinish(String s) {

            productList = new JsonConverter<Product>().toArrayList(s, Product.class);

    BindDictionary<Product> dict = new BindDictionary<Product>();

    dict.addDynamicImageField(R.id.ivImg, new StringExtractor<Product>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Product item, int position) {
            return item.img;
        }
    }, new DynamicImageLoader() {
        @Override
        public void loadImage(String url, ImageView imageView) {

            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(url, imageView); // Default options will be used
        }
    });
    dict.addStringField(R.id.tvCarModel, new StringExtractor<Product>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Product item, int position) {
            return "Car Model: " + item.Car_Model;
        }
    });
    dict.addStringField(R.id.tvCarType, new StringExtractor<Product>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Product item, int position) {
            return "Car Type: " +  item.Car_Type;
        }
    });
    dict.addStringField(R.id.tvCapacity, new StringExtractor<Product>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Product item, int position) {
            return "Capacity: " + item.Capacity;
        }
    });

    FunDapter<Product> adapter = new FunDapter<>(
            HomeActivity.this, productList, R.layout.layout_list, dict);
    lvProduct = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvProduct);
    lvProduct.setAdapter(adapter);
    lvProduct.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Product selectedProduct = productList.get(position);
    Intent in = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
    in.putExtra("product", (Serializable) selectedProduct);
    startActivity(in);
}
}
```

I learned this code on a youtube channel and I know i followed the instructions well and I'm always checking the intent and still the problem is there. Thank you Guys in advance. :)

This is my DetailActivity.class. Does this have my problem?

```
package com.example.kun.carcarkila;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;

public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView tvCarModel, tvCarType, tvCapacity;
ImageView ivImage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(UILConfig.config(DetailActivity.this));

    Product product = (Product) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("product");

    tvCarModel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvCarModel);
    tvCarType = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvCarType);
    tvCapacity = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvCapacity);
    ivImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivImage);

    if(product != null){
        tvCarModel.setText(product.Car_Model);
        tvCarType.setText(product.Car_Type);
        tvCapacity.setText(product.Capacity);
        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(product.img, ivImage);
    }
}

}
```

`Debug`

```
in = {Intent@830622078952} "Intent { cmp=com.example.kun.carcarkila/.DetailActivity }"
mAction = null
mCategories = null
mClipData = null
mComponent = {ComponentName@830622081720} "ComponentInfo{com.example.kun.carcarkila/com.example.kun.carcarkila.DetailActivity}"
mData = null
mExtras = null
mType = null
mPackage = null
mSelector = null
mSourceBounds = null
mFlags = 0
```

Comment: Have you checked to see if you're DetailActivity is running?  I'm wondering if perhaps that's kicking off the login activity.Also, if you comment out that "startActivity", I assume nothing happens?

Comment: How to check if my DetailActivity is running? I'm not also that very sure that My DetailActivity is working. Ill Edit my question and add my DetailActivity. @bryan

Comment: Just add a breakpoint in it to see if it's getting called.

Comment: Sometimes this behaviour is caused by some error. Instead of crashing, app goes to previous activity. It would be useful to look into your logcat to check if there aren't any errors that you missed.

Comment: `Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8601', transport: 'socket'` This is whats happening on the debug log when I'm clicking an item on the list view and it sends me one page back. @bryan

Comment: `intent = {Intent@830623297984} "Intent { cmp=com.example.kun.carcarkila/.DetailActivity }"
    mAction = null
    mCategories = null
    mClipData = null
    mComponent = {ComponentName@830623267952} "ComponentInfo{com.example.kun.carcarkila/com.example.kun.carcarkila.DetailActivity}"
    mData = null
    mExtras = null
    mType = null
    mPackage = null
    mSelector = null
    mSourceBounds = null
    mFlags = 0`
This is what's happening when im debbuging it. @spork